# Use c++ Code in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using unity3D for the first time to develop a game.I have written a code in c++ using Opencv and the code consist on many files.Now I want to apply the result computed by c++ code to a 3D character.
How i can use my c++ code in unity.Please help me.Remember I am using OpenCV Libraries in my c++ Code.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a DLL file and use it within Unity. There is many examples on how to do so.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

If you have some money you can also purchase the Unity source code that is written in c++ though that seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

did some googlefu...

> C++ is not a scripting language, and can only be used with Unity in the form of plug-ins (in the Pro version). C# is closer in syntax to C++ than Javascript is.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12809/can-i-use-c-as-a-scripting-lanques-for-unity.html
(couldn't find anything that contradicted that)

although these might be of interest: 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82518/is-it-possible-to-use-c-with-unity-instead-of-c
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/